# partial trust application woes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, full-trust, partial-trust

I am using Visual Studio 2015 WPF application, C#.

I have an program I just sent to my Beta testers.  The one using Windows 10 had big heartburn over my using "full trust". He needed to change registry values to allow it to install, then he changed the registry values back.

I don't want Win10 users to need to change registry values, so I changed it to a "partial trust application".  As a partial trust application, Zone internet, it just will not even open - it can't run.

I can not find help on how to specify the trust/permissions I need.

My application does the following:

```
    1. registry - creates keys/reads/writes
    2. does a socket server which listens on a port
       (another person's program on same computer
        attaches to this server)
    3. Uses audio devices
    4. General File I/O.
```

Can someone please point me to information on how to configure my program to work as a "partial trust" application?

If I can't figure this out, I will be forced to use some other installer.  I really like the online update in Microsoft's installer.

Thanks, and Regards,
Howard

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1252575/unable-to-install-clickonce-application-due-to-security-settings-windows-10

In a nutshell, It does not matter what permissions your ClickOnce applications asks for, or if it is a Fully Trust application.

What matters is the user's machine needs to PERMIT THE USER to be prompted.  I can't believe there are windows machines out there setup that the user never gets asked if he/she will allow this Full Trust application to be installed.

Sometimes I think all problems are caused by Microsoft?

Other reference material:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fcc52138-68d9-480b-a152-551f3b96f4bb/click-once-calculate-permissions-button-not-visible

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/krimakey/2009/05/20/where-did-my-permission-set-controls-go/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-configure-the-clickonce-trust-prompt-behavior?view=vs-2015

https://superuser.com/questions/1252575/unable-to-install-clickonce-application-due-to-security-settings-windows-10